# Convert the type ActiveRecord JSON output attribute to another type

Tags: json, activerecord, type-conversion

I have the following ActiveRecord model with `to_json` method overridden.

```
 
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso, :name
  def as_json(options={})
    result = super({:only => [:id, :name]}.merge(options))
    result
  end
end
```

I would like to convert the type of `id` which is an integer to a string. How can I do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this javascript? In javascript you would do something like

```
var id = 1;
id = id + ''; //Make it a string
```

See this topic: http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/how-to-convert-int-to-string-415083.html

Comment: No. It's Ruby on Rails. I know how to convert an integer to a string in Ruby but I want to know how to output a particular field in a string using ActiveRecord.